# javascript's string comparision and comparision operators were not working?

Tags: javascript

I'm working out javascript cookbook by shelley powers. And in the book,

> If two string literals only vary based on case, the uppercase characters are lexically
>   greater than the lowercase letter:

```
var sOne  = "Cat";
var sTwo  = "cat";
if (sOne >=  sTwo) // true, because 'C' is lexically greater than 'c'
```

but I cannot get the same result. this only works for me:

```
 var sOne = "Cat";
 var sTwo = "cat";
 if (sOne < sTwo) alert("whatever here");
```

Here it pops up a alert.I'm pretty confusion.Thanks guys!

Comment: Hmm, in ASCII upper case letters are less than the lower case ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book is incorrect. It's listed in [the errata](http://oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9780596806149).

Answer (score 1):

Uppercase A in ASCII and every code page I've encountered has a decimal value of 65.
Lowercase a has a decimal value of 97.

Therefore "A" < "a" and "Able" < "able".